# Using hbm2ddl with dual entity managers in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin

I'm trying to split a database into two parts and was wondering if there's a way in Hibernate to have two entity managers, but specifically mark certain entities to only be picked up by one of the two entity managers.

```
// setup primary DB
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default", paramsDefault.toTypedArray()))    

// setup audit DB
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("audit", paramsAudit.toTypedArray()))
```

In my config (this is only for dev, in production we won't be using hbm2dll), I have a line:

`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>`

On which entities will that be executed?

Is there a way for example to force this entity:

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "accounts")
data class Account(

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    var username: String = "",

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    var email: String = "",

    ....
```

to only be available when using the default entity manager and not the audit entity manager?

So in other words, how do I prevent the `Account` table being created on the `audit` database and the audit entities from being created in the `default` database?